# In EKS external connection to NodePort service open after deleting service

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, microservices, amazon-eks

I have a demo environment in AWS, running with EKS, Kubernetes. I defined an external service created with type NodePort

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: service-bird-front
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8443
  selector:
    app: ws1
```

When I run

```
kubectl get svc -A
```

Among other services I get:

```
default       service-bird-front       NodePort    10.100.179.224   <none>        443:30389/TCP    100d
```

I have one pod running for app ws1.

Then from the internet, from my laptop, behind a proxy and most probably with NAT, I can get a web page from the endpoint:

```
https://35.91.149.254:30389/assets/
```

35.91.149.254 is the external IP address of one of my EKS nodes.

Everything is working great, the web server returns the proper web page with the correct data.

However, when I delete the service service-bird-front with

Kubectl delete -f service-front.yaml

The service is deleted, as it corresponds, the pod behind the service is still running, and from the web site I still can access the web site. Using tcpdump I can see the internal connection between the node and the pod is maintained.

So with the service down, the web browser can still work with my application using port 30389.

Then, I create the service again:

```
kubectl apply -f service-front.yaml
```

I see the service again with a new NodePort:

```
default       service-bird-front       NodePort    10.100.140.214   <none>        443:31761/TCP    4s
```

And I can still access the web site in port 30389 with endpoint https://35.91.149.254:30389/assets/

When I change the node IP to another node's external IP, the service doesn't respond, I get "connection refused". When I try to connect from a different device, also "connection refused". That is what I expect as the correct behavior. However, in node with external IP 35.91.149.254, from the same device, it continues working. It is as if the TCP connection between the proxy and AWS is kept open forever and the TLS connection with my laptop's browser is kept forever. Only after I disconnect from the wifi and connect again, my browser receives "connection refused" error.

Is that a correct behavior? Shouldn't it stop responding on port 30389 as soon as I delete the service? Is this an error with AWS?

Thanks in advance for any explanation.

Comment: Could be a browser caching issue? Did you try incognito or cache clear and try?

Comment: @Raghu , I don't think so because I was able to continue adding and submitting data and the page got updated with the new data.